# Customized Circular Progress with svg image form MUI V5 using react ts

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, loader

[image]

Instead of normal blue circular progress, Can we add an image or icon for stroke of circular progress or linear gradient stroke in MUI v5 using react ts?

```
const rotate = keyframes`
  0% {
     transform: rotate(0deg);
     stroke-dasharray: 1 200;
     stroke-dashoffset: 0;
     stroke-width: 6px;
     opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
     stroke-dasharray: 89 200;
     stroke-dashoffset: -35px;
     stroke-width: 4px;
     opacity: 0.3;
  }
  100% {
     transform: rotate(360deg);
     stroke-dasharray: 89 200;
     stroke-dashoffset: -124px;
     stroke-width: 1px;
     opacity: 0.1;
  }`;

const StyledCircularProgress = styled(CircularProgress)(() => ({
 "&  .MuiCircularProgress-svg": {
  animation: `${rotate} 2s linear infinite`,
  width: "100%",
  height: "100%",
  strokeLinecap: " round !important",
  //  stroke: `linear-gradient(to right, ${colors.join(", ")}) !important `,
  stroke: `url(${progress_icon})`,
},
}));



<div>
  <Backdrop
    sx={{
      backgroundColor: "rgb(255 255 255 / 90%)",
      // color: theme.palette.primary.main,
      zIndex: (theme) => theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
    }}
    open
  >
    <StyledCircularProgress
      //   color="inherit"
      size="108px"
      variant="determinate"
      value={25}
    />
  </Backdrop>
</div>
```

Here I have specified the stroke to the URL of progress-icon. but i can't able to find the loader icon instead getting red color circular progress

Comment: Can you post your full code to run properly?